# Duplicate entry for class in gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to implement ken burns view in android studio in my app, i have importted the folder which contains its classes, but gradle gives me this error **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/flaviofaria/kenburnsview/MathUtils.class**

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "revamp.revamp2015app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.5.0.jar')
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6'


}
```

What should i do to make it run ?

Comment: have you imported the code?? and you have modified build.gradle also?? Reply so that I can help

Comment: yes i have imported the code and added compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6' to my gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above library is already on maven.
Just remove the imported folder and add the code below to your dependencies:

> compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6'

Sometimes due to downloading issues; the library fails to download. In that case ; just find your .gradle folder and clear cache inside it. Recompile and you are done

Comment: Thanks so much ,one doubt, if we write the above line in gradle, we do not need to separtely download and copy any libraries right ?

Comment: @penta yes, these are maven library dependencies. You needn't separately download.One more way- go to project structure , select module ->use +/- button on corner to add Library dependency ->and there you can search it over there. In some cases ; when it is not on maven; then it will be needed to download spearately

Comment: i am trying to implement kern burn view, any idea how to control the speed and duration of animation ?

Comment: @penta wish I could've helped you. Never used the library before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80695/discussion-between-penta-and-androidlearner).

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6'
```

with this one:

```
compile project(':FOLDER_NAME')
```

Where `FOLDER_NAME` is the name of the folder you imported to your project, after that sync your gradle.

Comment: i get Error:(30, 0) Project with path ':com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview' could not be found in project ':app'.

Comment: what is the name of the folder you imported? "library"?

Comment: compile project('com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview') i typed this

Comment: try this: compile project(':library')   , library refers to the default kenburnsview library folder name, but if you changed its name then type it correctly.