# Import a project to Android studio faced problems

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, open-source, build.gradle

I want reading an open source project so I select k9mail for start. The recommendation was run and reading this code in Android Studio. I import k9mail project to AS 1.2.1.1 version. I download gradle 2.4 version and added this in environment variable. When I want to run this application, but I receive some errors that I describe below:

1) When I click Run (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>), select Android Application, select my module (there is k9mail) and select USB Device, then I see a warning:

> No JDK specified for module 'k-9-master'.

2) When I click on Run (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>), I faced this error in messages tab:

> Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
>   Possible causes:
>   A)The project 'k-9-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.Open Gradle wrapper file 
>   B)The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

When I updated gradle to 2.4, I changed `classpath  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'` to 'classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4'' from build.gradle of k9mail, but my problems were not solved.

I googled but I can't find solutions for my problems.

Answer (score 0):

> No jdk specified for the module.

For that you have to specify the jdk path through Project Structure.
You may also verify by looking at `local.properties`

For gradle related issues you just kindly update your gradle build and SDKs to latest versions.
This will minimize your gradle issues.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I set JDK Location in below Sdk Location on Project Structure. I can't understand your mean of 'local.properties', you mean, i should set JDK on 'local.properties' like sdk.dir?

Comment: No local.properties will show you the current set location. You can verify from there. And if it helped please mark it as answer.cheers

Comment: Again i can't understand :( sorry... What should i do? Where i write anything? I update my SDK and Gradle to last version, but i have some gradle errors. Sure, if i can solve my problem with helping you, i'll mark your answer for helping to other user :)

Comment: Try clearing the cache and building again as in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863079/duplicate-entry-for-class-in-gradle/30863539#30863539